# android google indoor map

Tags: android, google-maps

Halo guys,i found that the google map apps can show indoor floor plan with stores name,
but as i just implement google map v2 into my Android apps, it only shows floor plan without stores, is it possible to show details like the google map apps?

second, is there a indoor routing system in google map v2 for indoor map? e.g. shop a to shop b in same building same floor, and more if same building different floor?

thanks!!

[image: goole map apps]

[image: my apps with google map v2 api]

Comment: I m trying something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708831/showing-place-names-on-google-indoor-map . I think markers are needed to be implemented :)

Comment: @Kenett : have you done with this problem. I just started to implement google indoor maps for some building. Require some information about implementation. Can you please help me for the same?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this by any chance ??

Answer (score 1):

No. You only get the basic outlines of the stores, not the names and such with indoor maps. Also there is no routing period in Google maps.

Comment: Is there any update to the sdk for retrieval of store details or it's still supposed to be manual ??