# getting Google places indoor data

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-indoor-maps

I am doing google maps indoor api for a mall. Google maps for android is only displaying floors without shop informations.

I checked this , https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007932/1602333

He's saying that use google places api for getting details about floors. But I couldn't find any floor information in this ,

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details?hl=en

The placeId which is I am using is , `ChIJ7418PMfIXzkRuJT-zFxZyN0` which is for `Inorbit Mall Vadodara`. i am not getting any floor information in details responce.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Found any solution to this one ??

Comment: @DeepLathia , No I stopped working on that project.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at how to display indoor maps from Google [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // Some buildings have indoor maps. Center the camera over
    // the building, and a floor picker will automatically appear.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-33.86997, 151.2089), 18));
    }
}
```

If you need to add floor plan, you can do it over [here](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685896?hl=en&ref_topic=3517937).

Comment: thnx for the answer. It's about adding indoor plan , i want store informations which is already showing on google maps app , but not in maps sample. It shows only floors , not the shops. Am I missing something or it's intended behaviour ?